# Selecting between two dates ignoring the year

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a way to properly selected between two dynamic dates ignoring the year.

```
Dates here are listed as mm/dd/YYYY
```

We have a list of expiration_dates, where the year is irrelevant to us.  I need to find all the records that land `between 1 and 4 months out` (30 and 120 days).  For example: If the current date is 11/01/XXXX, I would need to be searching between 12/01/XXXX and 02/01/XXXX.

Current Non-Working Solution:

```
SELECT expiration_date
FROM mytable
Where
    DATEDIFF( day, DATEADD( year, DATEDIFF( year, expiration_date, getdate()), expiration_date), getdate()) <= -30
    AND DATEDIFF( day, DATEADD( year, DATEDIFF( year, expiration_date, getdate()), expiration_date), getdate()) >= -120
```

The above works so long the boundaries does not go outside of the current year.

Sample Data:

```
10/17/2014
12/07/2015
05/28/2007
05/17/2013
02/27/2015
11/02/2010
```

Expected Result:

```
11/02/2010
12/07/2015
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Please explain a bit more what "1 to 4 months out means" and what date this is supposed to be based on.  Why would 10/17 be selected and not 2/07?

Comment: I am also not sure what exactly your criteria is, but I think you want to use DATEPART: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: @sam - Using datepart I can add months, yes.  But what happens when the months go over 12?  Unless there is a more intelligent way to add the months.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I apologize for not being more concise. If the current date is 11/01/XXXX, I would need to be searching between 12/01/XXXX and 2/01/XXXX inclusively.  02/07 would be too far forward.  I updated the data and expected result to more accurately define the problem.

Comment: What db are you using specificallly? @evade

Comment: @Adam - I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, sorry I tagged SQL I should specify.

Comment: Am I the only one who realized there's no `from` statement?

Comment: Do you want 1-4 months or 30-120 days? These are not the same ranges.

Comment: @eirikir - 1 - 4 months specifically, I posted the 30-120 to further explain what '1-4 months' out had meant exactly.

Comment: @evade Are dates irrelevant? If the current date is 11/02, would 12/01 match?

Comment: @eirikir - The months and days are relevant, the year is not relevant.  Think of it like a birth day.  I essentially have a list of birth dates and need to know whose is coming  up within the next 1 to 4 months.

Comment: @eirikir - My last statement contradicts myself.  I see that now.  It seems that I more accurately want the expiration dates in the next 30 to 120 days.  Although either solution would be easy enough to modify if needed.

Comment: @Adam - The original question only had the where clause as its the only item relevant here.  I am adding it for clarification however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can compare a modulo of the time difference in months to match the months and dates regardless the year. You would just need to handle the date for the first and last months in the acceptable range. I've done this below, but since I don't have SQL Server installed, I can't test how DATEDIFF works with months, but I'm assuming here it gives integers.

```
SELECT expiration_date FROM mytable 
  WHERE (DATEDIFF(month,GETDATE(),expiration_date) % 12 IN (1, -11) AND DATEPART(day,expiration_date) >= DATEPART(day,GETDATE()))
  OR (DATEDIFF(month,GETDATE(),expiration_date) % 12 IN (4, -8) AND DATEPART(day,expiration_date) < DATEPART(day,GETDATE()))
  OR (DATEDIFF(month,GETDATE(),expiration_date) % 12 IN (2, 3, -9, -10));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the criteria correctly, this should achieve the desired results:

```
SELECT expiration_date
Where
(DATEPART(month,expiration_date) BETWEEN 
(DATEPART(month,getdate()) + 1) % 12
AND DATEPART(month,getdate()) + 4) % 12)
AND DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),expiration_date) >= 30)

OR

(DATEPART(month,getdate()) + 4 > 12
AND DATEPART(month,expiration_date) <= DATEPART(month,getdate()) + 4) % 12
AND (DATEPART(month,expiration_date <> (DATEPART(month,getdate()) + 4) % 12
     OR DATEPART(day,expiration_date) < DATEPART(day,getdate()))
```

Comment: Fixing your suggestion to `DATEPART(month,expiration_date) BETWEEN DATEPART(month,DATEADD(month,1,getdate())) AND DATEPART(month,DATEADD(month,4,getdate()))` runs.

Comment: However, If I change the month parameters to 3 and 7 for testing purposes.  I get no results.  But the original 1 and 4 return results.  It seems once the month count goes past 12, it breaks.

Comment: @evade So i.e. if today is July, and you want to change the parameters to 3 and 7, you want months that fall later than October and before February?

Comment: @evade Edited results to include days

Comment: I had a tough time running this without errors, I accepted the other answer because it worked initially without any fiddling.  Thank you for your help!